# Animate RecyclerView additions from bottom

Tags: android, animation, adapter, android-recyclerview

I am using the latest RecyclerView library to display a list with an option to add items to this list. The list is in reverse order, so newest additions are displayed at the bottom. When adding new items to a recycler view from the top, a nice animation is displayed and the list is automatically scrolled to display the newest item.

However, when adding new items from the bottom, items are not similarly pushed up as the new item is being animated. This leads to odd behavior where a new item is added and the animation cannot be seen unless the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.

As a temporary fix, I've forced the recycler view adapter to scroll to the first position after adding a new item. This isn't as seamless as adding from the top of a recycler view, is there a proper way to implement this?

The corresponding code is below:

```
la.addItem(0, msg);
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. When you are scrolled to the very bottom of the list, the entire lift will shift upward and the new item will fade in place if you add it to the bottom.  If you add an item somewhere in the middle, then the bottom items below it will not move, but the top items will.n  Are you saying this isn't happening?

Comment: When the recycler view is showing a reverse layout, adding new items  appear at the bottom. The problem is that other list items are not pushed upwards as the new item is animated into the list. This creates a situation where newly added items are animated offscreen.

Comment: @TimMiller Did you got a solution of your problem...I am having same issue. When adding an item from bottom no animation

Comment: Nope. Ended up abandoning that view style and went for another layout that did not have an animation from the bottom. This was a total bummer!

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your adapter class

```
    public void addItem(Object aObject)
    {
        mAdapterList.add(aFormElement);
        notifyItemInserted(mAdapterList.size()); // Passing position where insertion happen
    }
```

If you are not getting animation than only use below function.
try to call scroll to position on recyclerview at your required position after calling addItem().